# Dataset for Data warehouse

Tags: dataset, data-warehouse

I am a final year IT student and I need a dataset to create a data warehouse. I tried searching on Kaggle and on open data but could not find the right one. Is there any source for a large free data set I can use for Business Intelligence purposes? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a few - AdventureWorks is the one I've used in the past.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15